# User logged out between Api requests

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I have React as front-end and Asp.net core Web API as back-end.
User management in back-end is using Identity.

I have a test that first logs in and then tries to get a plan belonging to the user.

The login is done successfully but after that when getting the plan, the user is not logged in anymore.

React test:

```
  const loginModel: UserLoginModel = {
    email: "n@b",
    password: "Aa123456!",
    rememberMe: true,
  };
  await accountApi.accountLoginPostRaw({ userLoginModel: loginModel }); //**Successful**

  const model: PlanPlanIdGetRequest = {
    planId: 15,
  };
  await planApi.planPlanIdGet(model); //**fails - http response 405**
```

User login:

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email).Result;
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user?.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Ok(new { message = "Login successful" });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(new { message = "Login failed" });
                }
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

Get plan:

```
        [HttpGet("{planId}")]
        [Authorize]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Plan), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPlan([FromRoute] int planId)
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var plan = await _dataBase.Plans.FirstOrDefaultAsync(plan => plan.PlanId == planId && plan.UserId == userId);
            return plan == null ? NotFound() : Ok(plan);
        }
```

because the function above uses [Authorize] I get 405 - meaning user is not logged in.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Http405  indicates you were sending  post request to  the endpoint that only allow get method,It should be 401 for not authenticated user .

Comment: but if I remove the [Authorize] data annotation from getPlan, I don't get the error, and when entering the function (which wasn't entered with [Authorize]) userId is null...